# why does a show "function getFullYear() { [native code for Date.getFullYear, arity=0] }" rather than the value returned by the method?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In the Google Apps Script Editor I have the following code

```
  function t(){
    var d = new Date;
    Logger.log(d);
    var y = d.getFullYear;
    Logger.log(y);
    if (y == 2013) {
      Logger.log("yes");
    } else {
      Logger.log("No");
    }
  }
```

I see the following results when viewing the log.

```
[13-06-23 19:53:52:863 PDT] Sun Jun 23 19:53:52 GMT-07:00 2013
[13-06-23 19:53:52:864 PDT] function getFullYear() { [native code for Date.getFullYear, arity=0] }

[13-06-23 19:53:52:864 PDT] No
```

I thought I would see an integer or perhaps a string that is the value returned by getFullYear.

Whatever is causing this problem for me is not unique to this method.

I am sure this is pretty basic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This stores a reference to the `getFullYear` function in `y`:

```
var y = d.getFullYear;
```

This calls the `getFullYear` function and stores the result of the function call in `y`:

```
var y = d.getFullYear();
// ------------------^^
```

Perhaps you're confused because you can create objects with or without the parentheses (assuming you don't need to pass any arguments of course):

```
var d1 = new Date;
var d2 = new Date();
```

Both of those do the same thing but that's just a quirk/feature of the `new` operator.

Comment: Thanks. The next sound you hear will be me slapping my forehead and saying "on, fer dumb.)

Comment: @WesR: My forehead is dented enough so I don't do that to myself anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

you just need parentheses after fourth line`var y = d.getFullYear;`
your corrected code is: `var y = d.getFullYear();`

Answer (score -1):

var y = d.getFullYear; chanege var y = d.getFullYear(); your problems must solve with this way. you forgot that "()"

Comment: Already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267607/9193372)... and accepted. No need to add the same answer.